# read from second line to end using Memory Stream

Tags: c#

I am new to C# . Is there any API to read a Memorystream from second line to last line without reading line by line using a loop as shown below.

```
   using (TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(inputStream))
   { 

        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
        string line;
        while ((line = textReader.ReadLine()) != null)
           data.Append(line+ System.Environment.NewLine);
   }
```

Note:- inputStream is of type MemoryStream

Comment: Call `ReadLine()`, then `ReadToEnd()`?

Comment: The only way is to move the position of the stream to the end and then move backwards until you find two returns.  The bytes between the two returns are the line you want.